# Cannot use VersionAdmin with a database that does not support savepoints

Tags: django, postgresql, django-reversion

I use django-reversion and I am getting this error out of the blue.

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot use VersionAdmin 
>   with a database that does not support savepoints.

It occurs on the line  `admin.site.register(Post,PostAdmin)`

Cannot use python manage.py on my local, though everything works fine in my production.

Have even tried changing the database(postgresql) but to no avail.

Comment: What database are you using?... does it support savepoints?

Comment: Postgresql. It worked absolutely fine until now. It is still working fine in my production not in local, eventhough I am working with the same database as production.

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot use manage.py" also, any other errors?

Comment: It gives the error (mentioned in the question)

Comment: @Sayse When i remove the PostAdmin line, and run manage.py, I get a 400 bad request error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that settings did not take my database.

I was using local settings which had a typo error. And it was not showing error because in try, except block, I did not write ImportError.